# Android how to publish beta version of App on Manage Releases page

Tags: android, google-play

On Google Play Developer Console, I am searching away to publish App from Beta Channel to Production Channel(**Promote to Prod**) On Manage Releases page, I was using APK page but

> The APK page will soon be fully replaced by the Manage Releases page.

on the following, what i was doing on APK page.

[image]

Comment: I vote to my question to be close.. thanks

Comment: But... "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"!

Comment: @ChrisRae, i am with you, this question used directly from developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the following steps:

Step one: **prepare release**:

1-Press Create release on Manage Release Page

2-Choose Add APK From Library

3-Select your beta version.

Step Two: **Review and rollout**:

if you get the follwing message:

> This release is ready to be rolled out.

Press On Start rollout